# VirtualPC: Can't boot into anything

Tags: virtual-pc

I am playing around with [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en) and following [Phil Haack's instructions](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/06/installing-ubuntu-on-virtual-pc-for-windows-lovers.aspx) for how to get ubuntu (because why not?) running on it.

I start up my virtual pc and during boot it just stays on the line that says DHCP.....

Capturing the ubuntu iso doesn't change this and eventually it tells me to Reboot and select proper boot device which - again - does nothing.

I feel like I must be missing some step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set cd-rom as first device in bios? yes, you have to do that, they think its fun.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?  I do not see this as an option anywhere

Comment: press F2 or Delete at start-up, go to bios and i think in 4th meanu put cd-rom on top using page-up/page-down.

Comment: Hmm, oddly the device order was set properly already.  But by setting the iso while on that screen it started to work.  Strangeness